# When to choose Terrans and how to make the most from them

Tags: gaia-project

I love Gaia Project. But there are some races I havn't quite "cracked" yet. So I figured I would try to start a thread here for each race. I will try with this one, and if people like it, I will follow up with each of the other races in turn.

I will start with one of the races I do think I've got a fair handle on.

I will then provide a response with the do's and don'ts that I've figured out so far.

Some things are always relevant before you choose a race. Such as the amount and layout of the planets. The more planets of the right colour, the better. Even more so, if there are planets nearby, that only needs to be terraformed a single step to become habitable. And hopefully they are not all situated near the border of the map. You also want to start near other players. No need to address these points each and every time.

So: When to choose Terrans, and how to make the most from them?

Summary of the Terrans, for those who do not remember : 
Start one place up the Gaia tech track, making you start with one of the three terraformers activated.
Once the Planetary Institute has been built, every Gaia phase, you may obtain resources for the powerdiscs that are moved back into your power bowls. 4 discs for a QI cube. 3 discs for an Iron. 4 discs for a Tech. 1 disc for a Gold.

Answer (score 5):

Terrans will become more attractive to pick, the more of the following are true:

- You are able to pick starting positions, where you can use your terraformer. Ie. the purple planet is next to or close to a blue planet. Preferably both your starting planets.
- During the first or second turn, you will get bonus points for building your Planetary Institute
- During the game, you will get bonus points for colonizing Gaia planets.
- The round booster giving points for colonized Gaia planets is available.

During the game, you will probably want to:

- Get your Planetary Institute on the board early, enabling your special ability to obtain stuff for free during the Gaia phase.
- Get hold of the tech tile, which allows you to take a special action giving you 4 power.
- Use this tech tile in combination with your terraformer. Use the terraformer to move a bunch of power tokens from your 1-bowl into the Gaia bowl. In the next turn, these will return to your 2-bowl. And with the special action, your will quickly have 4 power pushed into your 3-bowl. Once they are spent, one of your last actions that turn, should be to use your terraformer, thereby emptying your 1-bowl. Clean-rinse-repeat.
- If one of the late game turn bonuses is the 4-points for colonizing Gaia Planets, you may want to go deep in the Gaia tech track, enabling you to terraform three purple planets on the turn just before that, and then follow up with colonizing three Gaia planets and netting 12 points.
- If it suits your plans, you may also want to pick up the tech tile, that gives you 3 points every time you colonize a Gaia planet. The earlier the better.

Comment: I think it would be good to include a summary of the race's special abilities in the answer; for those who don't remember which races are which by name.

Comment: Good point. But I think then that should be put in the question. And not each and every answer. :)

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it made more sense in the question or answer; either sounds good.

Comment: As a side note. We played Gaia Project last night. The layout looked Terran-friendly. I picked last, and the Terrans were still available, so I took them. 199 points. BUGGER! One point shy of 200 points. Still new personal best, though.